# How to create an array in Javascript from the TD of an HTML table

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question concerning the management of the array in javascript.
I have an HTML table and I have two arrays, the first contains the TD of the first TR, while the second array contains the TD of the second TR.
Each TD of the first TR has the colspan attribute that defines the number of TD of the second TR that are connected to him.
See the Example of my HTML table below where CITIES and NATIONS are the TD of the first TR, while ROME MILAN ITALY GERMANY and POLAND are the TD of the second TR:

```
         CITIES            NATIONS
      ROME    MILAN       ITALY   GERMANY POLAND
```

The CITIES TD has the colspan attribute set to 2 (because the first 2 elements of the second TR are connected to CITIES). The same is for the NATIONS TD  that has the colspan to 3 because it spans the 3 columns: ITALY GARMANY and POLAND.

I posted below my code, but it is not complete.
I was able to create the array that contains the TD of the first row, the array that contains the TD of the second rows and then I got also the values and the colspan attribute of my TD of the first TR. 
What I need to do is to create a final array that will contain the following values written in this way:

> ROME-CITIES, MILEN-CITIES, ITALY-NATIONS, GERMANY-NATIONS, POLAND-NATIONS.

Do you know how I can create this array with the information I have ()?

```
    // I take the first TR (CITIES NATIONS)
var Firstheader = $("table#" + id + " thead tr:eq(0)");
    // I put in Firstheader_fields the cells of the first TR
var Firstheader_fields = $("td", Firstheader );

    // I take the second TR (ROME MILAN ITALY GERMANY POLAND)
    var Secondheader = $("table#" + id + " thead tr:eq(1)");
   // I put in Secondheader_fields the cells of the first TR
var Secondheader_fields = $("td", Secondheader);


//mio codice
for (index = 0; index < Firstheader_fields.length; ++index) {
    var MyCol = Firstheader_fields[index].innerHTML;
        var MyColspanFirstheader_fields[index].getAttribute('COLSPAN');
}
```

I think that I need to work with the COLSPAN because is, for example, the COLSPAN of CITIES is 2, I know that I need to take the first and the second element of the second TR and concatenate the value with CITIES.. but I don't know how to write this loop -.-'
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the function which will do just that. If you remove all the comments, empty lines and console.log()s it has 18 lines. Could be more compact, but I wanted to keep it easy to understand.

```
function tableHeadersToArray(headerElement1, headerElement2){

    //- Put all header1 > td elements in a collection
    var row1tds = headerElement1.getElementsByTagName('td');

    //- Make an array containing all colspans in order [1, 2, 1, 1, ...]
    var header1Colspans = [];
    for(var index=0; index<row1tds.length; index++){
        header1Colspans.push(row1tds[index].getAttribute('colspan') || 1);
    }

    //- Put all header2 > td elements in a collection
    var row2tds = headerElement2.getElementsByTagName('td');

    //- This is the tricky part
    //- Draw 2 arrays, one below the other on a pice of paper
    //- and place your 2 index fingers at the beginning of each one.
    //- Your left index finger is index1, and your right is index2.
    //- Follow the code, and each time one is incremented, move it
    //- to the right one cell.

    var colspan, index1=0, index2=0, resultingArray=[];

    //- (colspan = header1Colspans.shift()) gets the first element of the array,
    //- assigns it to var colspan and the expression has the value TRUE if the
    //- assignment was made, or FALSE if there were no more elements in the array
    while(index1 < row1tds.length && (colspan = header1Colspans.shift())){
        while(index2 < row2tds.length && colspan > 0){
            console.log(row1tds[index1].textContent, row2tds[index2].textContent, index1, index2, colspan);

            //- Here we concatenate 'ROME' + '-' + 'CITIES' and add it to the array
            resultingArray.push(row2tds[index2].textContent + '-' + row1tds[index1].textContent);

            index2++;
            colspan--;
        }
        index1++;
    }

    console.log(resultingArray);
    return resultingArray;

}
```

You can call it similar to this:

```
var header1 = document.querySelector('table tr');
var header2 = document.querySelector('table tr + tr');
tableHeadersToArray(header1, header2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code,  I will check It and I ll let you know

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have an html table similar to below:

HTML code:

```
<table cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <colgroup span="5" width="85"></colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2 height="17" align="center" valign=middle><font face="Liberation Mono,Courier New,Nimbus Mono L,DejaVu Sans Mono">         CITIES </font></td>
    <td colspan=3 align="center" valign=middle>NATIONS</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="32" align="left"><font face="Liberation Mono,Courier New,Nimbus Mono L,DejaVu Sans Mono">      ROME     </font></td>
    <td align="left">MILAN</td>
    <td align="left"><font face="Liberation Mono,Courier New,Nimbus Mono L,DejaVu Sans Mono">ITALY</font></td>
    <td align="left"><font face="Liberation Mono,Courier New,Nimbus Mono L,DejaVu Sans Mono">GERMANY</font></td>
    <td align="left"><font face="Liberation Mono,Courier New,Nimbus Mono L,DejaVu Sans Mono">POLAND</font></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can solve your problem by following javascript code

Javascript Code:

```
var Header =  {};
var otherRows =  [];

$('table').find('tr').each(function(index,value){
    if(index == 0){
      // Header values
      $(value).find('td').each(function(innerIndex,innerval){
        Header[$(innerval).attr('colspan').trim()] = $(innerval).text().trim();
      })

    }else{
      // other rows
      $(value).find('td').each(function(innerIndex,innerval){
        otherRows.push($(innerval).text().trim());
      })
    }
})
var finalArray = [];
$.each(Header,function(index,value){
  var colspan = index;
  for(pos=0; pos < colspan;pos++) {
    finalArray.push(otherRows[pos]+'-'+value);
  }
  for(pos=0; pos < colspan;pos++) {
    otherRows.shift();
  }
})

console.log(finalArray)
```

You can check here:

https://jsfiddle.net/eLh39yrj/1/

Comment: Hi thanks for the code but it supposes that i have just one table in my html page with just to rows, while I have a lot of tables. I need to do this on a table that i click on it and I need to create the array just considering the first 2 rows. Thankss